# Netty Recommended Buffer Size

Tags: java, networking, tcp, operating-system, netty

I've been trying to understand Netty's FrameEncoders. Specifically DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder. In a [couple](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=io.netty.handler.codec.Delimiters) of the [examples](https://programmer.group/netty-decoder-related-delimiterbasedframedecoder.html) I've [encountered](https://github.com/sanshengshui/netty-learning-example/blob/master/netty-helloworld/src/main/java/com/sanshengshui/netty/server/ServerInitializer.java#L23) the buffer size, [8192](https://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatClientInitializer.html#50) (bytes?) seems to pop up. Is there any specific reason as to why this size is chosen? As a best practice? Can it be increased and What would be the impact of increasing this size? What is the factor to consider while setting up this size?

Comment: DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder is used for text based protocols. 8192 is a random number, it can be anything you want. But probably it is chosen because it is a multiple of 1024, which is 8K.  Use any number that is suitable for your protocol. If the accumulated ByteBuf surpasses the number given to DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder you get a TooLongFrameException. This exception will be delivered to your inbound handler

Answer (score 1):

Often the limit itself is defined by the protocol you implement. For example SMTP may have different limits than IMAP. So its really up to you and the protocol you want to implement. The most important bit here is that there should be a limit as otherwise it would be trivial to trigger high memory usages on a remote system.